How to Implement Drone Identification Using Camera, Coordinates, and Orientation in React Native?
I’m developing a feature in a React Native application where I need to open the camera and point it towards drones flying in the air. The idea is to identify a specific drone by cross-referencing its real-time data (coordinates, altitude, and orientation) with the drone’s actual position in the camera view.
Here’s how it should work:
I have multiple drones in the air, each with data including latitude, longitude, altitude, and orientation.
When the user points the camera at a specific drone, the app should verify that the camera is aligned with the drone based on the provided data.
If the data matches, the app will display details about that specific drone.
I want this feature to ensure accuracy. The app should confirm the identification based on the drone’s data before showing any information.
Questions:
How can I calculate the alignment mathematically to verify that the drone in the camera view matches the provided data?
(e.g., any algorithms or formulas for comparing real-world data with a camera’s field of view?)
What libraries or tools would you recommend for implementing this feature in React Native? (e.g., AR libraries, mapping tools, or camera frameworks?)
Any suggestions ?
I’ve been searching for a mathematical explanation or formula to solve this problem, but I haven’t found a clear answer yet. Specifically, I’m trying to figure out how to calculate whether a drone’s real-world data (latitude, longitude, altitude, and orientation) aligns with the camera’s field of view.
I’ve explored various libraries and resources:
Checked AR libraries like react-native-arkit and ViroReact to see if they provide built-in tools for matching real-world objects with camera views.
Looked into GPS and bearing calculations to project drone positions, but I’m unsure how to incorporate altitude and the camera’s perspective to achieve accurate results.
I’m still trying to find the right mathematical approach and potential libraries that could simplify this task. Are there any pre-built solutions or best practices for implementing such a feature in React Native?
